# How to place large text with numbers next to smaller text in the top left/right corner of a shape?

Tags: html, css

Here's the code I'm working with:

```css
 ul {
    color: beige;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item px-3 border-0 rounded-3 mb-2" style="background-color: #8A8583;">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="justify-content: center;">
          <h2 style="color: beige; font-weight: bold; margin: auto;">I also code lots of      side-projects that are either websites or applications using a wide variety of languages.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><h1 style="font-size: 7rem;">03</h1></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Which creates the shape with text and everything but I want it to look more like

[image: this].

How might I be able to move the larger number to the top left and such?

I've tried `floating: left`, `floating: right`, and removing the `justify-content: center`, and nothing has worked. I was expecting it to revert to the center left of the column when removing these things but unfortunately nothing happened. Even adding something like pull-right doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `flex` and properties of it such as `justify-content` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

You may simply create same as in this snippet I did:

```css
 .items {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: flex-start;
            border-radius: 50px;
            background-color: #8A8583;
            padding: 20px 40px;
        }

        .items .left {
            width: 70%;
        }

        .items .left h3 {
            /* text-align: justify; */
        }

        .items .right h1 {
            font-size: 70px;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="items">
        <div class="left">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi modi, iste odit delectus vitae, dignissimos iusto non mollitia quae ipsum repellendus nobis doloremque esse blanditiis! Maiores vitae officia iusto inventore.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <h1>03</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `justify-content` property the element also has to be `display: flex` (or `display: inline-flex`).

What's the CSS for the `row` class? It doesn't seem to be keeping those two elements on a single line. That's where I'd be applying flex. Trying making that row `display: flex`. You might also need a `text-align: right` on the second column.

`justify-content: center` seems like the wrong value for the first column, given that the design is left-aligned.

Try something like

```
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 style="color: beige; font-weight: bold; margin: auto;">I also code lots of      side-projects that are either websites or applications using a wide variety of languages.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: right;">
    <h1 style="font-size: 7rem;">03</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` on the container to achieve this, also add margin to the left column and remove margins from the h1 like this:

```css
ul {
    color: beige;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item px-3 border-0 rounded-3 mb-2" style="background-color: #8A8583;">
  <div class="row" style="display: flex">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2 style="color: beige; font-weight: bold; margin: auto; margin-right: 50px;">I also code lots of      side-projects that are either websites or applications using a wide variety of languages.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><h1 style="font-size: 7rem; margin: 0">03</h1></div>
  </div>
</li>
```